# how to adjust width and height of the tab in jsf2 primefaces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

[image]

How to adjust the width and height of the tab in jsf 2 primefaces. Also please tel me how to control the text(color and font size) inside the tab? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PrimeFaces uses the ThemeRoller CSS Framework. Go to the [jQuery UI ThemeRoller page](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) and create your own theme.  Download the CSS file and include in your .xhtml pages.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/skin.css" />
```

Add this to your web.xml so the default theme is not used:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It is much easier to create a new theme then to figure which CSS rules to override to make the tabs look the way you want.

---

The [jQuery UI tabs page has a section on Theming](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) and the CSS rules it uses.

The tab width changes depending on the length of the text and the height is determined by the font-size.

To increase font size override the following CSS to something like this:

```
.ui-tabs {
    font-size:1.3em;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..i saw in the primefaces user guide that they use yui skinning..is the yui skinning same as the one you mentioned or different? is there any scheme that i can download which is similar to the primefaces default theme and then override as you said because currently i have developed my application using primefaces default theme..i dont want the users to give a different feel to the application entirely..

Comment: @user1234 They are not the same. PrimeFaces uses two Javascript APIs, YUI(Yahoo) and jQuery. The PrimeFaces p:tabView uses jQuery UI tabs.

Comment: @user1234 are you using an older version of PrimeFaces? ThemeRoller themes were introduced in version 2.1, before that I think it was using yui-skinning.

Comment: i am using primefaces 2.2.1.i will try with the themeroller themes..in case of any clarifications i will need your help..thanks..are there any jsf primefaces examples to work with the themes? please let me know..

Comment: @user1234 The PrimeFaces website has some [pre-built themes](http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html) available, if you didn't want to create your own.

Comment: @MarkRobinson could you please show the overriding of the primefaces?

Comment: @sys_debug to override, create your own CSS file, in that CSS file use the same class names and properties from the CSS that comes with PF that you want to change.