# How to change PrimeFaces size of accordion panel?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, liferay, portlet, portal

How to change PrimeFaces size of accordion panel? I run my portlet over Liferay Portal. 
Tabs look so huge. I want to create small tabs. I tried to change (increase or decrease) size of tabs like this but it didn't help me:

```
<p:accordionPanel style="height:40px; width:100px;">
// tabs...
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can try this.
Link is : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495814/how-to-adjust-width-and-height-of-the-tab-in-jsf2-primefaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495814/how-to-adjust-width-and-height-of-the-tab-in-jsf2-primefaces)